# What to include in HTTP location header if POST multiple items?

Tags: rest, http

It is a good practice to include a location header as response to POST, but if multiple items are created at the same request, what should I do to the response? One location header with multiple URIs or multiple location headers and one header only includes one URI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a RESTful service one POST request should create one resource. If your POST leads to the creation of several resources, your POST can be seen as referring to a resource that is a container of several other sub-resources. I'd suggest you use this resource (the container-resource) in your header.

Comment: I highly doubt about "one POST request should create one resource"

Comment: @Can I was writing this in answer to the question. Of course a POST can do other things too (like manipulating a resource). But the question here was what to put in the header of a 'response to POST, but if multiple items are created at the same request'.

Answer (score 0):

"Location" can only be used to send a single URI.